# Why I am getting FileNotFoundException while converting Video Uri to Bytearray?

Tags: android

I am converting Video Uri to bytearray but I am getting FileNotFoundException

I have written this code for converting Video Uri to bytearray

```
               video = data.getData();
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                FileInputStream fis;
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(new File(video.getPath()));
                    int n;
                    while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
                        baos.write(buf, 0, n);
                    fis.close();
                    baos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 bbytes= baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Uri does not have to resolve to a file. It can be *virtual*. You don't need to create a `File` from it, you can read bytes from Uri

Comment: @SaeedEntezari 1) no need to add even a single `!` to your comment, as you should not scream on other people here. 2) Your comment is wrong itself. There are a lot of other reasons why `FileNotFoundException` exception might be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try open stream with `ContentResolver`:

```
fis = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(video);
```

Comment: can I use this instead of yours , fis= (FileInputStream) getContentResolver().openInputStream(video);

Comment: You can cast it; but if just need get bytes from Uri, you can use just `InputStream` without requiring details of it implementation

Comment: I am not able to use context, I am getting error so I have typecasted .Please let me know if context is not working what to use ?